# Laravel Account models

Tags: php, object-oriented, laravel, eloquent

This library is part of an accounting system. Two major models are involved. For every transaction there is an entry in the `AccountTransaction` model and corresponding 2 entries in the `AccountJournal` model. For non-cash entries, reference details go to `AccountTransactionDetail` model. How can the code be rewritten more efficiently? I see lot of repetition in it.

```
<?php

namespace App\Libraries;

use App\AccountPeriod;
use App\AccountTransaction;
use App\AccountGroup;
use App\AccountLedger;
use App\AccountJournal;
use DB;
use Auth;

class Accounts
{
    protected $entity = [];
    protected $period;
    protected $ledgerWise = false;
    protected $discounts;
    protected $balances;
    protected $ledgers = [];
    protected $reference;
    protected $amount;
    protected $paymentMode;

    /**
     * Entity involved in the transaction
     *
     * @param $entity_type
     * @param $entity_id
     * @return \App\Libraries\Accounts
     */
    public function entity($entity_type, $entity_id)
    {
        $this->entity = [
            'type' => $entity_type,
            'id' => $entity_id,
        ];
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Accounting period
     *
     * @param \App\AccountPeriod $period
     * @return \App\Libraries\Accounts
     */
    public function period($period)
    {
        $this->period = $period;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Ledgerwise results
     *
     * @return \App\AccountPeriod
     */
    public function ledgerWise()
    {
        $this->ledgerWise = true;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Calculates account balance of an entity
     *
     * Returns ledger wise balances or aggregate balance
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function balances()
    {
        $balances = AccountJournal::having('total', '>', 0)
            ->whereHas('ledger', function ($q) {
                return $q->where('name', 'Accounts Receivable');
            });
        if (isset($this->period)) {
            $balances->ofPeriod($this->period);
        }
        if (!empty($this->entity)) {
            $balances->ofEntity($this->entity['type'], $this->entity['id']);
        } else {
            $balances->groupBy(['entity_type', 'entity_id']);
        }
        if ($this->ledgerWise) {
            $balances->select(['linked_ledger_id AS ledgerId', 'account_ledgers.name AS ledgerName'])
                ->join('account_ledgers', 'account_journals.linked_ledger_id', '=', 'account_ledgers.id')
                ->groupBy(['ledgerId']);
        }
        return $balances->addSelect(['entity_type', 'entity_id', DB::raw('SUM(amount) AS total')])
            ->get();
    }

    /**
     * Discounts given to account
     *
     * @param array $discounts Associative array of ledger wise discounts
     * @return \App\AccountPeriod
     */
    public function discounts($discounts)
    {
        $this->discounts = $discounts;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Processes payment against an account
     *
     * Calculates balances, adjusts discounts given (if any)
     * and posts to relevant ledgers
     *
     * @return bool|void
     */
    public function pay()
    {
        if (empty($this->getEntityType())) {
            return false;
        }
        $this->processDiscounts();
        switch ($this->getMode()) {
            case 'Cash':
                $debitLedger = $this->getCashLedger();
                $tranType = 'Payment';
                break;
            case 'Bank':
                $debitLedger = $this->getBankLedger();
                $tranType = 'Payment';
                break;
            case 'Adjustment':
                $debitLedger = $this->getDiscountsLedger();
                $tranType = 'Journal';
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        if ($this->getAmount() <= 0) {
            return;
        }
        DB::transaction(function() use(&$t, $debitLedger, $tranType) {
            $t = AccountTransaction::create([
                'period_id' => $this->getPeriod(),
                'entity_type' => $this->getEntityType(),
                'entity_id' => $this->getEntityId(),
                'type' => $tranType,
                'amount' => $this->getAmount(),
            ]);
            if ($debitLedger->name != 'Cash') {
                $t->detail()->create([
                    'ref_id' => $this->getReferenceId(),
                    'ref_date' => $this->getReferenceDate(),
                    'ref_desc' => $this->getReferenceDesc(),
                ]);
            }

            foreach ($this->getBalances() as $balance)
            {
                if ($this->getAmount() >= $balance->total) {
                    $amount = $balance->total;
                    $this->amount($this->getAmount() - $amount);
                } else {
                    $amount = $this->getAmount();
                    $this->amount(0);
                }
                AccountJournal::create([
                    'period_id' => $this->getPeriod(),
                    'entity_type' => $this->getEntityType(),
                    'entity_id' => $this->getEntityId(),
                    'ledger_id' => $this->getReceivableLedger()->id,
                    'linked_ledger_id' => $balance->ledgerId,
                    'transaction_id' => $t->id,
                    'amount' => -($amount),
                    'created_by' => Auth::id(),
                ]);

                AccountJournal::create([
                    'period_id' => $this->getPeriod(),
                    'entity_type' => $this->getEntityType(),
                    'entity_id' => $this->getEntityId(),
                    'ledger_id' => $debitLedger->id,
                    'linked_ledger_id' => $balance->ledgerId,
                    'transaction_id' => $t->id,
                    'amount' => $amount,
                    'created_by' => Auth::id(),
                ]);
                if ($this->getAmount() == 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            // If there is no balance, consider advance
            if ($this->getAmount() > 0) {
                AccountJournal::create([
                    'period_id' => $this->getPeriod(),
                    'entity_type' => $this->getEntityType(),
                    'entity_id' => $this->getEntityId(),
                    'ledger_id' => $this->getAdvancesLedger()->id,
                    'transaction_id' => $t->id,
                    'amount' => -($this->getAmount()),
                    'created_by' => Auth::id(),
                ]);

                AccountJournal::create([
                    'period_id' => $this->getPeriod(),
                    'entity_type' => $this->getEntityType(),
                    'entity_id' => $this->getEntityId(),
                    'ledger_id' => $debitLedger->id,
                    'transaction_id' => $t->id,
                    'amount' => $this->getAmount(),
                    'created_by' => Auth::id(),
                ]);
            }
            return $t;
        });
        return $t;
    }

    /**
     * Payment mode for the transaction
     *
     * @param $mode Payment mode
     * @return \App\Libraries\Accounts
     */
    public function mode($mode)
    {
        $this->paymentMode = $mode;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Amount for the transaction
     *
     * @param $amount Amount
     * @return \App\Libraries\Accounts
     */
    public function amount($amount)
    {
        $this->amount = $amount;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Reference details for the transaction
     *
     * @param $ref_id
     * @param null $ref_date
     * @param null $ref_desc
     * @return \App\Libraries\Accounts
     */
    public function reference($ref_id, $ref_date = null, $ref_desc = null)
    {
        if (is_array($ref_id)) {
            $this->reference = $ref_id;
        } else {
            $this->reference = [
                'id' => $ref_id,
                'date' => $ref_date,
                'desc' => $ref_desc,
            ];
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Adjusts discounts against balances, ledger wise
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function processDiscounts()
    {
        if (!$this->getDiscounts()) {
            return false;
        }

        foreach ($this->getBalances() as $balance)
        {
            if (in_array($balance->ledgerId, array_keys($this->getDiscounts())) &&
                $this->getDiscounts()[$balance->ledgerId] > 0) {
                DB::transaction(function () use($balance) {
                    $t = AccountTransaction::create([
                        'period_id' => $this->getPeriod(),
                        'entity_type' => $this->getEntityType(),
                        'entity_id' => $this->getEntityId(),
                        'type' => 'Journal',
                        'amount' => $this->getDiscounts()[$balance->ledgerId],
                    ]);

                    $t->detail()->create([
                        'ref_id' => $this->getReferenceId(),
                        'ref_date' => $this->getReferenceDate(),
                        'ref_desc' => $this->getReferenceDesc(),
                    ]);


                    AccountJournal::create([
                        'period_id' => $this->getPeriod(),
                        'entity_type' => $this->getEntityType(),
                        'entity_id' => $this->getEntityId(),
                        'ledger_id' => $this->getReceivableLedger()->id,
                        'linked_ledger_id' => $balance->ledgerId,
                        'transaction_id' => $t->id,
                        'amount' => -($this->getDiscounts()[$balance->ledgerId]),
                        'created_by' => Auth::id(),
                    ]);

                    AccountJournal::create([
                        'period_id' => $this->getPeriod(),
                        'entity_type' => $this->getEntityType(),
                        'entity_id' => $this->getEntityId(),
                        'ledger_id' => $this->getDiscountsLedger()->id,
                        'linked_ledger_id' => $balance->ledgerId,
                        'transaction_id' => $t->id,
                        'amount' => $this->getDiscounts()[$balance->ledgerId],
                        'created_by' => Auth::id(),
                    ]);
                });
            }
        }
        unset($this->balances);
    }

    /**
     * Account balances
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getBalances()
    {
        if (!isset($this->balances)) {
            $this->balances = $this->ledgerWise()->balances();
        }
        return $this->balances;
    }

    /**
     * Receivable ledger
     *
     * @return \App\AccountLedger
     */
    public function getReceivableLedger()
    {
        if (!isset($this->ledgers['receivable'])) {
            $this->ledgers['receivable'] = AccountLedger::whereName('Accounts Receivable')
                ->first();
        }
        return $this->ledgers['receivable'];
    }

    /**
     * Discounts ledger
     *
     * @return \App\AccountLedger
     */
    public function getDiscountsLedger()
    {
        if (!isset($this->ledgers['discounts'])) {
            $this->ledgers['discounts'] = AccountLedger::whereName('Discounts')
                ->first();
        }
        return $this->ledgers['discounts'];
    }

    /**
     * Advances ledger
     *
     * @return \App\AccountLedger
     */
    public function getAdvancesLedger()
    {
        if (!isset($this->ledgers['advances'])) {
            $this->ledgers['advances'] = AccountLedger::whereName('Advances')
                ->first();
        }
        return $this->ledgers['advances'];
    }

    /**
     * Cash ledger
     *
     * @return \App\AccountLedger
     */
    public function getCashLedger()
    {
        if (!isset($this->ledgers['cash'])) {
            $this->ledgers['cash'] = AccountLedger::whereName('Cash')
                ->first();
        }
        return $this->ledgers['cash'];
    }

    /**
     * Bank ledger
     *
     * @return \App\AccountLedger
     */
    public function getBankLedger()
    {
        if (!isset($this->ledgers['bank'])) {
            $this->ledgers['bank'] = AccountLedger::whereName('Bank')
                ->first();
        }
        return $this->ledgers['bank'];
    }

    /**
     * Accounting period
     *
     * @return $id Accounting period id
     */
    public function getPeriod()
    {
        if (!isset($this->period)) {
            $this->period = AccountPeriod::active()->first()->id;
        }
        return $this->period;
    }

    /**
     * Entity type of transaction
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getEntityType()
    {
        return $this->entity['type'];
    }

    /**
     * Entity id of transaction
     * 
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getEntityId()
    {
        return $this->entity['id'];
    }

    public function getDiscounts()
    {
        return isset($this->discounts) ? $this->discounts : false;
    }

    public function getReferenceId()
    {
        if(isset($this->reference)) {
            return $this->reference['id'];
        }
        return null;
    }

    public function getReferenceDate()
    {
        if(isset($this->reference)) {
            return $this->reference['date'];
        }
        return null;
    }

    public function getReferenceDesc()
    {
        if(isset($this->reference)) {
            return $this->reference['desc'];
        }
        return null;
    }

    public function getMode()
    {
        return $this->paymentMode;
    }

    public function getAmount()
    {
        return $this->amount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> #### How can the code be rewritten more efficiently? I see lot of repetition in it.

Yes there is a lot of repetition in the code. The most common thing I spot is multiple places where `AccountJournal::create()` is called with an array with common elements.

In the `pay` method, inside the `foreach` loop in transaction- an array of common props to pass to `AccountJournal::create()` could be abstracted to a variable, or better yet, perhaps a method on class `Accounts` could be made to create the journal entry with parameters for the values that change - e.g.  'ledger_id', 'linked_ledger_id', 'transaction_id', 'amount'. Then that method can be called whenever a journal entry needs to be created.

The created_by value could be set automatically - e.g. by an observer or [closure event handler](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events-using-closures) method.

### Other suggestions

#### Break up the elephant

The class `Account` is quite lengthy- partly because of methods like `pay` and `processDiscounts`. Those methods could likely be broken up into smaller methods - e.g. after `pay` calls `processDiscounts` it could call a method to set `$debitLedger` and `$tranType` based on the return value of `this->getMode()` instead of the somewhat long `switch` statement.

Consider whether it makes sense to break that monstrous class into multiple sub-classes - perhaps one for each mode (i.e. *adjustment*, *bank*, *cash*, etc.

#### Use the null coalescing operator

> ```
> public function getDiscounts()
> {
>      return isset($this->discounts) ? $this->discounts : false;
> }
> ```

Bearing in mind this code was posted at the end of 2017, hopefully the server is running PHP 7.3 or newer (at least from security standpoint given [LTS](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php)) and with version 7 the [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) can be used to simplify lines like that return statement.

```
return $this->discounts ?? false;
```